# SQLite: excluded int primary key null value replaced with next auto value

Tags: unique-constraint, auto-increment, upsert, sqlite3

I'm trying to create generic upsert query builder with specific behavior. Table has two unique constraints: primary key *itId* and column *slug*:

```
create table it (
    itId integer primary key -- an alias for rowid
  , slug text
  , text text
  
  , CONSTRAINT "itId" UNIQUE("itId")
  , CONSTRAINT "slug" UNIQUE("slug")
);

-- fill the table:
insert into it
    (itId, slug, text)
values
    (null, 'a', 'letter a')
  , (null, 'b', 'letter b')
  , (null, 'c', 'letter c')
;
```

| itId | slug | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | letter a |
| 2 | b | letter b |
| 3 | c | letter c |

Then, here's an attempt of batch upsert of rows using different keys:

```
insert into it
    (itId, slug, text)
values
    (null, 'a', 'latin letter a') -- update text by slug
  , (   2, 'β', 'greek letter beta') -- update slug and text by primary key
  , (   9, 'c', 'latin letter c') -- update primary key and text by slug
on conflict (itId) do update set
    text = coalesce(excluded.text, text)
  , itId = itId -- save current value for autoincremented column
  , slug = coalesce(excluded.slug, slug)
on conflict (slug) do update set
    text = coalesce(excluded.text, text)
  , itId = coalesce(excluded.itId, itId) -- here's a trouble!
```

(I'm using [SQLite 3.35](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_35_4.html), which allows multiple `on conflict` clauses)

| itId | slug | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | β | greek letter beta |
| **4** | a | latin letter a |
| 9 | c | latin letter c |

As you can see, `b` changed to `β` -- that's okay; `c` has changed its *itId* according to upserted value `3` -> `9`. But there's a trouble with `a` (was matched by slug): *excluded.itId* resolves with a value `4` instead of `null` within second `on conflict` clause. It seems that the value of *itId* for row `a` is replaced with the next available autoincrement value for column *itId* (an alias of *rowid*).

Expectation: `itId = coalesce(excluded.itId, itId)` => `coalesce(null, 1)` => `1`:

| itId | slug | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | a | latin letter a |
| 2 | β | greek letter beta |
| 9 | c | latin letter c |

Is there a way to achieve such a result using `insert ... on conflict do update` for all of these cases?

[Online playground](https://sqlime.org/#deta:rwfs8hlesabw)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that substitution of null with a new rowid happens before the conflict is evaluated.
A solution is to change `itId` from `integer primary key` to `int primary key`. This specific syntax will have sqlite to not substitute `itId` for `rowid`, so you will have both a separate autoincremented `rowid` column and your `itId` column.

After any insert in the table, you have to set `itId` to the same value of `rowid` for those rows where you inserted null. You can do it automatically with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS trg_it AFTER INSERT ON it
WHEN new.itId is null
BEGIN
UPDATE it SET itId=new.rowid where rowid=new.rowid;
END;
```

This way your second insert can correctly make use of `excluded.itId`

[Your updated playground](https://sqlime.org/#deta:do3tsvsy4le2)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer